# How are dynamic priorities of threads computed in Linux 2.6.x?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pthreads, scheduled-tasks

A thread (or task) will loss dynamic priority by using a lot of cpu and gain priority by using less of CPU. How exactly are these priorities computed for n threads (using normal scheduling policy SCHED_OTHER )?

Comment: The Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS), a.k.a. SCHED_NORMAL or SCHED_OTHER, is documented [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt) and implemented [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/fair.c).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [this document](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/os/prac/linux_cpu_scheduler.pdf), section 5.4.2:

> The Linux 2.6.8.1 scheduler rewards I/O-bound tasks and punishes
> CPU-bound tasks by adding or subtracting from a task’s static
> priority. The adjusted priority is called a task’s dynamic priority,
> and is accessible via the task’s `prio` variable (e.g. `p->prio` where `p`
> is a task). If a task is interactive (the scheduler’s term for I/O
> bound), its priority is boosted. If it is a CPU hog, it will get a
> penalty. In the Linux 2.6.8.1 scheduler, the maximum priority bonus is
> 5 and the maximum priority penalty is 5. Since the scheduler uses
> bonuses and penalties, adjustments to a task’s static priority are
> respected. A mild CPU hog with a nice value of -2 might have a dynamic
> priority of 0, the same as a task that is neither a CPU nor an I/O
> hog.

I feel this is a fair explanation. The priority is computed based on whether it is a CPU bound thread or an I/O bound one. And regarding what you mentioned in the question, that *gain priority by using less of CPU* is rather gain priority by being interactive(I/O bound). I hope this excerpt answers your query...